# UWP on Xbox One. UI gets dim (darker) after 10 minutes

Tags: uwp, xbox

I'm developing a surveillance UWP App for Xbox One, if there is no interaction (from the controller) after exactly 10 minutes, the screen gets automatically dim (darker), real time video continues to show perfect in the screen but very dark.

Looking trough internet, I found several people (not programmers, just users) complaining about this, because it apparently happens also when they are watching streaming video or bluray.

They talk for possible solutions as:
- Connecting the headphone: I tried, it doesnt solve the issue.
- Turning off the console: neither.
- Resseting to factory settings: I prefer not to do it.
I read in some post that with October update, that would have been solve, but I have november update and its annoying.

Is there any command, or capability that I can implement from code, to avoid this behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't this like a standard console behavior, to dim the screen if inactive? I see this on xbox all the time if I leave it. Maybe there is some API available to keep it active even if long time without interaction passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DisplayRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx) class to notify the system that you do not want the device to enter in power saving mode (dim screen, lock device etc...).

```
 m_displayRequest = new DisplayRequest(); 
 m_displayRequest.RequestActive();
```

Once done or when the app gets suspended, you will have to release the display request:

```
m_displayRequest.RequestRelease();
```